# Populate CheckBoxList inside Datalist ItemTemplate from database SQL Server 2012 asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, checkboxlist, datalist

I have a table of diseases in database MS SQL Server 2012.
disease_id int
disease_name varchar(100).
What i want is to populate the checkboxlist from db.
My file .aspx part is :

```
<div style="width: 100%; float: left">
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" Width="350px">
        <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <ItemStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkbxlistDiseases" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField='<%#Eval("disease_name") %>' DataValueField='<%#Eval("disease_name")%>'>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    </asp:DataList>
</div>
```

and My file .cs part is :

```
void PopulateDiseases()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str_con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select disease_name from diseases", con);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    CheckBoxList checklist = DataList1.FindControl("chkbxlistDiseases") as CheckBoxList;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        checklist.Items.Add(dr["0"].ToString());
    }
}
```

the error is :

```
 {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
```

at this line of code

```
checklist.Items.Add(dr["0"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
checklist.Items.Add(dr["disease_name"].ToString());
```

or

```
checklist.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
```

Also check if `checklist` is null. If that is the case, you should use a recursive FindControl method you can easily find on StackOverflow

Comment: Sorry, I think I have misunderstood the question. Where do you call PopulateDiseases and how do you DataBind the DataList1?

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the CheckBoxList, you must look for it in each item of the DataList. The code below shows how you can do it. I have set the field `disease_id` as the value of each check box, but you can put back `disease_name` if you prefer.

The markup:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkbxlistDiseases" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField='disease_name' DataValueField='disease_id' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

The code-behind:

```
void PopulateDiseases()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str_con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select disease_id, disease_name from diseases", con);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    foreach (DataListItem item in DataList1.Items)
    {
        CheckBoxList checklist = item.FindControl("chkbxlistDiseases") as CheckBoxList;
        checklist.DataSource = dt;
        checklist.DataBind();
    }
}
```

The function `PopulateDiseases` must be called after `DataList1` has been filled.

An alternative approach would be to populate each CheckBoxList in the `ItemDataBound` event handler of the DataList. In that scenario, the disease table (`dt`) could be declared and filled outside of the event handler to avoid multiple calls to the database.